# Consume AZURE ML with nodejs error 400 status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a problem when I try to consuming the web service, the error is:

```
The request failed with status code: 400 
{"error":
{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid argument provided.",
"details":[{"code":"BatchJobInputsNotSpecified","message":"The following required input(s) were not specified with the request: input1. Please ensure all input data is specified and try again."}]}}
```

I don't know how to solve that, because in the code I send `input1`.

Please help me, thanks.

```
let req = require("request");

    const uri = "bla";
    const apiKey = "key";

    let data = {
        "Inputs": {
            "input1":
            [
                {
                    'IdEmpleado': "20000",
                    'NivelSatisfaccion': "0.38",
                    'SatisfaccionLaboral_Disc': "Insatisfecho",
                    'UltimaEvaluacion': "0.53",
                    'UltimaEvaluacion_Disc': "Media",
                    'ProyectosRealizados': "2",
                    'ProyectosRealizados_Disc': "[2-3]",
                    'HorasMensuales': "157",
                    'HorasMensuales_Disc': "[150-199]",
                    'Antiguedad': "3",
                    'Antiguedad_Disc': "[2-4]",
                    'AccidentesTrabajo': "0",
                    'AccidentesTrabajo_Disc': "NO",
                    'Ascendido': "0",
                    'Ascendido_Disc': "NO",
                    'AreaTrabajo': "Ventas",
                    'NivelSalarial': "Bajo",
                    'Renuncia': "1",
                    'Renuncia_Disc': "SI"
                }
            ],
        },
        "GlobalParameters": {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scoring uri expects the body of the request to be a JSON document with the following structure:

```
{
    "data":
        [
            <model-specific-data-structure>
        ]
}
```

The structure of the data needs to match what the scoring script and model in the service expect. Please follow the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service#request-data) for more information.